# Знаки пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Доброго всем здравия.
Правильно ли я расставил знаки пунктуации?
Пример:

> *Когда девушка говорит - "нет", это значит - "не знаю".
>
> Когда девушка говорит - "не знаю", это значит - "да".
>
> Когда девушка говорит - "да", это не девушка.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, можно расставить знаки препинания в соответствии с предложенной EkaterinaKas... схемой. Можно также поставить тире перед главным предложением вместо запятой, если в предложении имеет место интонационное подчеркивание. Ставить интонационные тире для обозначения пауз между любыми членами предложения, в том числе и данными (закавыченными словами), Вам запретить никто, конечно, не может, но есть ли здесь эти паузы?

Comment: Пример Икара - это пособие для начинающих мужчин. "А пример приведён для примера, и не более". Примеров можно было взять тысячи других, но Икар выбрал именно этот.

Comment: @русак, для начинающий мужчина? Интересно здесь значение слова "начинающий", т.е. начинающий что именно? Стареть? Готовиться к выходу на пенсию? Готовиться к смерти?  
@И.Кар взял этот пример, что первое пришло в голову. Так как в голове у меня совсем другие примеры. Так как я технарь.

Comment: А что тут непонятного? Если мальчик хочет стать мужчиной, он использует Ваше Пособие для общения с женщинами

Answer (score 4):

Когда девушка говорит "нет", это значит  "не знаю".
Когда девушка говорит  "не знаю", это значит  "да".
Когда девушка говорит  "да", это не девушка.

Только смысл  высказывания сомнителен и спорен. Правда, это уже другая история.

Comment: to @EkaterinaKas...
Я не про смысл выражения хотел узнать, а хотел узнать про правильность применения и расстановки знаков пунктуации.  
А пример приведён для примера и не более.